# Use fn key as globe  key on first-generation Magic Keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

macOS lets you assign an action to the  (globe) key:

[image]

This setting works on a modern keyboard with combined  <kbd>fn</kbd> key:

[image: globe/fn key]

But my first-generation Magic Keyboard doesn't have the globe symbol on its <kbd>fn</kbd> key:

[image: old fn key]

This seems to be more than just a visual difference. On my Magic Keyboard, it only works as a plain <kbd>fn</kbd> key, and the action assigned to the  key ("Show Emoji & Symbols") doesn't work.

Is there a way to have the first-generation Magic Keyboard's <kbd>fn</kbd> key act like a modern  <kbd>fn</kbd> key?

Comment: Are these both connected to the same Mac, on the same macOS?

Comment: Yes, same Mac and macOS.

Comment: Then I'm guessing it's reading the keyboard 'live' I will disable the feature if it's not present. idk what difference is sent by the key. You could try [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware)
 & see what each is actually sending.

Comment: How old is the keyboard?  My iMac 2017 keyboard has only fn on the key and works just fine to show emoji and symbols.  Does Character Viewer work from the bottom of the Edit menu?

Comment: That's interesting that it works for you. My Magic Keyboard is from 2020, with integrated battery and Lightning port. The Character Viewer does work from the bottom of the Edit menu, just not when I press the fn key on the Magic Keyboard. On the internal keyboard it works fine.

Comment: for me it works double tapping the fn key in my first magic keyboard

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem, but after upgrading to the latest version of Monterey (12.6), it is now working:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I since upgraded to a new Magic Keyboard with a globe symbol ( <kbd>fn</kbd>), but the emoji window still doesn't show reliably when I press it, so I think the premise of this question is wrong. It's actually not about globe symbol at all.

I've made a follow-up question for this problem: [Globe 🌐 (fn) key doesn't open emoji picker with external keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446893/globe-fn-key-doesnt-open-emoji-picker-with-external-keyboard)

Comment: Were you also only talking about clamshell mode when you ask the question 6 months ago?

Comment: @TomGewecke I *think* so, but I'm not sure. I only properly figured out that "external keyboard + clamshell mode" is a contributor to the problem when I wrote the follow-up question.