# External keyboard’s globe  (fn) key doesn't open emoji picker in clamshell mode

Tags: macos, keyboard, emoji

In the Keyboard settings of my MacBook, I have selected "Press  (globe) to Show Emoji & Symbols":

[image]

While this works fine on the internal keyboard, pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>  on an external Magic Keyboard doesn't open the emoji picker when my MacBook is in the clamshell mode, that is when its lid is closed.

Is there a way to make it work?

*Update:* Actually, sometimes it doesn't work, and sometimes it does. It seems random so far.

Answer (score 4):

The Globe key doesn't work when the lid is closed, but it does work when the lid is open. That maybe explain the randomness.

As a workaround you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to open the emoji picker.

Answer (score 0):

The  <kbd>fn</kbd> key on my MacBook Air's keyboard was not triggering the Emoji picker window.

I came to this question, and saw the recommendation to press <kbd>⌃⌘ Space</kbd>. I did so and the Emoji picker immediately opened.

After doing so, the  <kbd>fn</kbd> key *immediately started working again*. Perhaps the emoji picker process had crashed; the spacebar shortcut seems able to relaunch the process while the globe / function key does not.